# How can i get .keystore file for generating encrypt your private key

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, private-key

for generate encrypt your private key i have need .keystore file but i don`t know where is located it

i have .jks file alias name and password

please help

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't believe that a filename extension tells you everything about a file. I've never heard of a *.keystore* format, but I have heard of JKS (now deprecated) format for java KeyStore files.

Comment: then how can i encrypt  private key for my app
have any idea ? @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk